# How to know if a user is facebook logged in? Django

Tags: django, django-facebook

As the title indicates, I would like to know how to do to distinguish a user that is logged in with facebook from a user that is logged in by mail. I'm using django-facebook.

It seems that

```
 request.user.is_authenticated()
```

is for every kind of authentification.

Any help would be welcome,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can check if request.user has a [FacebookProfile](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/blob/master/django_facebook/models.py#L177):

```
{% if request.user.facebookprofile %}user has facebook profile{% endif %}
```

Or in python:

```
if request.user.facebookprofile_id:
    print 'has facebookprofile'
```

Comment: thank you, I tried but I get this error : 'User' object has no attribute 'facebookprofile_id'

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. I had to add the name of my custom user profile: request.user.userprofile.facebook_id. Thank you for your help.